# Gridlines in excel through interop

Tags: excel, interop

Any idea where the setting is hiding for turning gridlines off while using excel 2003 from interop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DisplayGridlines is a method on an Excel Window object. 
For example:

```
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = true
```

Answer (score 4):

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel.Application oXL;
oXL.Windows.get_Item(1).DisplayGridlines = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
oXL.Windows.Application.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;
```

write the code just before save excel code line.

Comment: Seems this is the only snippet that actually pops up as members in Visual Studio, nice going

Answer (score 2):

Currently, using `VS2012` and I did it as follows:

```
Excel.Application oXl = new Excel.Application();

oXl.Visible = false; // true for debug

Excel.Workbook wb = oXl.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];

oXL.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false; //true is the default in Excel
```

Comment: I have not set them, and they are off, so I'm not sure true is the default.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).DisplayGridlines = True 'OR False`