# Create new worksheets using VBA not showing the zero values

Tags: excel, vba, show, zero

If a worksheet does not exist, I create a new worksheet wit the command

`Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)`.

I don't want to see the zero values in these sheets but don't know how to do this in VBA. I want to do this with a VBA instruction.

Comment: What do you mean with "the zero values"?

Comment: If the value in a cell is "0", then this value is displayed. What I want is that if the value is zero (0), that the cell is left blank. I can change that for each worksheet in "Options", but I want to set this for each sheet I create to set this in VBA.

Comment: What you are describing is a property of a [worksheet view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34028720/11683), not the worksheet itself. Although you can "truly" hide zeroes in all views by applying a corresponding [numeric format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32172418/11683).

Comment: GSerg, thank you very much for your help. This is the solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to show zeros as blanks.

```
ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False
```